# Android overlay scrollview by programatically adding a fragment on top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, scrollview

Im making a layout in which i have a "header", and below it a scrollview. Below the header, i want to add another fragment that should be drawn on top (i.e. overlay) the scrollview. I currently have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Content -->

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This of course does not achieve what im trying to do. I *could* add another container view below my initial fragment container, and let that be the overlay. But i'd much prefer to keep everything within a single fragment. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need is make something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/overlay_view"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Content -->
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And when you want to show the overlay_view just programmatically set the visibility to visible:

```
LinearLayout overlay_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlay_view);
overlay_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```